# Passar parâmetros de cabeçalho do Web Service?

Tags: angularjs, web-service, post

Estou tentando realizar uma chamada de web service no AngularJS, no entanto estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem de erro no console do navegador(testei no chrome e Firefox):

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8083' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Pelo o que entendi o `soap` ***reclamou*** que eu não enviei os cabeçalhos da requisição. Realmente o serviço exige cabeçalhos conforme abaixo, no entanto não sei como passá-los no parâmetro da chamada `post`, apenas enviei os parâmetros do `body` da requisição.

Parâmetros do cabeçalho: usuário e loja:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"

   <soapenv:Header>
      <v1:header>
         <usuario>?</usuario>
         <loja>?</loja>
      </v1:header>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:inImprimirFatura>
         <tipo-fatura>?</tipo-fatura>
         <numero-cpf>?</numero-cpf>
      </v1:inImprimirFatura>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Service que faz a chamada post:

```js
function GerarSegundaViaFaturaTotvsPDF()
{
 var metodo = 'imprimirFatura';
 var url = '
 var param = {};        
 param.tipoFatura = "ATUAL";
 param.CPF =
 return $soap.post(url, metodo, {req: param});         
}
```

Como passo os parâmetros de cabeçalho na chamada de forma simples sem mudar a estrutura do meu código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geralmente esse tipo de erro está relacionado com o [CORS](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing).

Neste post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource você pode verificar melhor e tem mais duas referências explicando o conceito. Uma delas cloquei acima.
Abaixo segue a citação do post que acredito que tenha a ver com o seu problema:

> If I understood it right you are doing an XMLHttpRequest to a different domain than your page is on. So the browser is blocking it as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons. You need to do something different when you want to do a cross-domain request. A tutorial about how to achieve that is Using CORS.